# CreateRawTransaction and SendRawTransaction how to specify transaction fee?

Tags: transaction-fees

I am able to createrawtransaction and sendrawtransaction but how am I able to specify a transaction fee for the miners?

I am looking at possibly large transaction sizes due to multiple inputs (around 100) and I have had a few of them never show up to their destinations and some of them do show up. I am assuming this might be due to the lack of transaction fees since I am using the exact same code to send both raw transactions.

So again, how can I specify a transaction fee in Bitcoind with creating a raw transaction.

And by the way, I am spending the funds from a multisignature address, in which 2 of the private keys are not controlled locally, so settxfee will not suffice. I want to write it into the transaction itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The transaction fee is specified by the difference of the sum of inputs and the sum of outputs, i.e.

```
transaction fee = Σ(inputs) - Σ(outputs)
```

In other words, you set a transaction fee by sending more than you assign to the recipient.