# Error sendrawtransaction BTC 0.21 Fee exceeds maximum configured by user

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, rpc-error-25

How to fix Fee exceeds maximum configured by user (e.g. -maxtxfee, maxfeerate) (code -25) in BTC 0.21?

```
sendrawtransaction "hexstring"

Result:

Fee exceeds maximum configured by user (e.g. -maxtxfee, maxfeerate) (code -25)
```

Comment: Check `bitcoin.conf`

Comment: fallbackfee=0.00002
paytxfee=0.00002
maxtxfee=0.01
mintxfee=0.00000002

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/22871/75551